# get value from unselected checkbox

Tags: html, c++, checkbox

i got a problem with checkbox in html usage.

I have some checkboxes with some names which are already loaded.In which some are checked(tick) by default, now i want to do unselect the checkbox which are checked by default and select the other checkbox which was unselect, Here how can i find out which was unselected in list of checkboxes. i read about hidden field but not getting much idea.

Eg: having 10 checkboxes with diff. name and 4 are checked by default and i was unselecting the checkbox and selecting the other two 
how to get unselected checkbox name and value.
i m doing with c++ with html no jquery

Thanks in advance and help me to get out from this.

Comment: Are you talking about the CHtmlView class from MFC?!? Or why is this question c++ flagged, if you seem to have a problem with HTML?!?!?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i m performing this using c++ with html i.e if i get the value and name  string from unselected checkbox then i ll store the strings for further functionality.

Comment: Is jQuery an option ?

Comment: @pugazh , i don't know much jquery .can you suggest me in using hidden field while selecting and deselect checkbox in html

Comment: Thanks for the snippet but it's different in my case.because i already wrote a code with loading of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery a solution, try this.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        this.checked = !this.checked;
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Toggle</a>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="t" value="1" checked>1
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="t" value="2" checked>2
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="t" value="3">3
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="t" value="4">4
<br/>
```